# Counting Chart series from a worksheet [by name]

Tags: vba, excel, collections, syntax, series

I have searched through the forums and I cant find an exact solution to my problem. I am somewhat familiar with vba and coding in general but I am still very new to the VBA syntax. I keep getting errors along the times of syntax error, object not in range, etc. I want to get away from selection based actions and I want to call specific charts from sheets to count the amount of data series within.

It seems so simple and at this point im just frustrated I havent been able to actually debug it. I have tried a lot of different combinations and have been Googling all morning and all I get is new and different error messages. So I figured one of you may have a quicker solution than my tinkering. Any help would be super helpful, thanks!

```
Dim SheetName As String
Dim SC2 As Long
SheetName = ActiveSheet.Name 'assign the name of the active sheet to the variable

'Count # of series in chart to find # of loops required
ActiveWorkbooks.Sheets(Volume CT).ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection.Count
'*^^^THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS*
'Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Time CT").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection.Count
'Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Temp CT").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection.Count
```

Comment: What is the actual error you get? also does `VolumeCT` hold the name of your sheet or is it the actual name of the sheet?

Comment: For this exact coding, I get Compile error: Syntax. 

I believe that Volume CT is the name of the sheet and the chart - however to work around this I tried assigning a variable to the name of the active sheet. then I called the variable in the next line. see below 

When changed to: ActiveWorkbooks.Sheets(SheetName).ChartObjects(Volume CT).Chart.SeriesCollection.Count I get the expected seperator or ) error

Comment: `ActiveWorkbooks` >> `ActiveWorkbook`   And what is `Volume CT` ?  that's not a variable since it has a space, so likely you want quotes around that

Comment: @TimWilliams Volume CT is the name of the Chart [and sheet i think]. When I place quotes around the name, I get the error 1004 "Application-defined or object defined error"

Comment: Is your chart in a Chart Sheet or is it in a regular worksheet?

Comment: It may be a chart sheet. I didnt create the file so im not 100% sure but this could be the solution. @TimWilliams how would I reference a chartsheet differently?

Comment: See the edit in my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim SC2 As Long

'chartobject method (chart is housed in a regular worksheet)
SC2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Volume CT").ChartObjects(1).Chart.SeriesCollection.Count

'if the chart is on a chart sheet:
SC2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Volume CT").SeriesCollection.Count
```

Comment: It worked! thank you tim! 

anyone just reading this - this answer satisfies the condition of referencing a ChartSheet to then go into series collection. NOT for regular charts within a sheet

Comment: @CoreyChung Both options are covered